# spring-cloud-config fallback server

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

Can spring-cloud-config be configured to have more than one config server? So that if one would fail, it would fall back to another one?

If that is possible, and the 2 severs are using filesystem instead of git, is there a sync between those, or do both have to be updated manually?

Answer (score 2):

1. I did not find this directly in config server. But you can use discovery service as eureka and have as many config server instances as you want: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#eureka-first-bootstrap
2. From docs: "To scale the Config Server up and make it highly available, you would need to have all instances of the server pointing to the same repository, so only a shared file system would work. " you can use rsync for that.